# Changing back from default

Tags: display-template

terminology in this question is probably wrong since I am a new user

When I tried to delete an app from Sharepoint a prompt told me that I had to change the layout of my website before I could proceed; I clicked okay, and that changed the layout of "site contents" and the lists. One of the Things that happened is that I got a search bar on top of my list.

How can I change the site back to how it used to be? Also, how can I change back to this? (I really like the search bar)

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @ChrisG Sharepoint 2016

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works in SharePoint 2013, hopefully some of this transfers to 2016.

Is it Site Layout or View Layout?

**Site Layout** is located under (Settings > Site Settings > Change the look(under Look and feel)) By default the current site thumbnail in the top left and then see the "Site Layout" drop down to change it from Seattle or Oslo. Each style has a change to the left navigation on or off.

**View style** in SharePoint 2013 the "Default" view style contains some view links and the "Find a file/item" search box. Just go to your App/List/Library and open the List/Library ribbon > modify view > review the "Style" section to ensure it is set to "Default".

Comment: Well, my Sharepoint is in Norwegian. So, I tried removing another app to see which one it was, and all it says is that I have to use the "classical Version of Sharepoint" to delete the app since they have not added the feature yet.... I guess the Company I work for is using some sort of beta version of Sharepoint.

Comment: Well, I found what happened to the lists; It changed from New experience to classic experience.

Comment: nice, glad you figured it out. feel free to mark this as answered if your problem was solved.